# How to show only pdf in filepicker?

Tags: android, filepicker

I am using this `compile('com.droidninja:filepicker:1.0.8')` library in my app gradle. How to display only in pdf need to remove other extension.

Github path: https://libraries.io/github/AndroidVinay/Android-FilePicker

Comment: Are you using any intent to search only for pdfs in mobile?

Comment: use addFileSupport()

Comment: This is a 3rd party library specific question . If it does not provide any method then you can not do this directly. But you can modify it your way.. Read the library's [ReadMe.MD](https://github.com/AndroidVinay/Android-FilePicker/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: \\ if my answer works .. please mark it as accepted answer .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As stated in lib documentation :

If you want to add custom file type picker, use `addFileSupport()` method like this (for pdf support):

```
       String[] pdfTypes = {".pdf"};
       addFileSupport("PDF", pdfTypes, R.drawable.ic_pdf_icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intentPDF = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intentPDF.setType("application/pdf");
    intentPDF.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intentPDF, PICK_FILE_PDF);
```